# How to prevent values from being converted to strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
    var str;
    var displayedNum;
    for (i in imgURLArray){
        str = "<li photonum="+i+">" + "<a>"+ (1+i) + "</a>" + "</li>";
        $("ul.selection-list").append(str);

}
```

I need to do this within a loop, but what happens is it prints out "11" instead of "2", because it converts to string before addition.

I have the same problem if I try to do the addition outside of the string and store in a variable as well, it still converts to string instead of doing addition.

Number(1+1) still converts to string first before turning it into a number, so it comes out 11.

Comment: This will solve your problem: `... + 1 + +i + ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use parenthesis:

```
var str = "foobar" + (1+i) + "other stuff";
```

> I have the same problem if I try to do the addition outside of the string and store in a variable as well, it still converts to string instead of doing addition.

It should not. My guess is that you are doing something wrong there too.

**Update:** It seems you are converting `i` to a string somewhere in the code you did not post.

**Update 2:** [Don't use `for..in` to loop over an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description). Use a normal `for` loop if it is really an array:

```
for(var i = 0, l = imgURLArray.length; i < l; i++)
```

But if it is an objects:

`for...in` will always set `i` as a string (as it loops over the properties of the object which are not always integers) . That means you would have to convert `i` *before* you do any addition:

```
... + (1 + (+i)) + ...
```

**Update 3:**

You don't always have to use such an "explicit" for loop. For example, you can traverse the array in reverse order, which makes the head shorter:

```
for (var i = imgURLArray.length; i--; ) {
    str = "<li photonum="+i+">" + "<a>"+ (1+i) + "</a>" + "</li>";
    $("ul.selection-list").prepend(str);
}
```

Comment: @BenB.: Then please post more of your code. It works: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/XfDwd/ I assume you are converting `i` to a string somewhere.

Comment: for...in will set i as a string? What is the rational in that??

Comment: @BenB.: `for...in` is used to loop over properties of objects, like: `obj = {foo: 'bar'}; for(var i in obj){console.log(obj[i]}`. Clearly, `foo` is not an integer.

Comment: @Ben Are you sure that the properties of `imgURLArray` are numbers and not strings?

Comment: Okay well read that thing on for...in. Won't ever use it from now on I guess... too bad... I much prefer it to the explicit loops.

Comment: @BenB.: Read why it should be avoided. Not only is it bad practice,  it is also much slower than a for loop: http://jsperf.com/array-for-in-vs-fo

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping numbers in Number()

Like:

```
var i = 1;

var str = "foobar" + Number(1+i) + "other stuff";
```

Comment: Attempts to typecast the parameters as Numbers rather than adding them together as Strings.

Comment: @c-smile `Number(x)` casts the value of `x` to the Number type.

Comment: Nope. Converts to string first, so it is converted to number after the "string" is concatenated, e.g., Number(1+1) = 11

Comment: Works fine for me though? My output was: **foobar2other stuff**

Comment: @BenB.: Only an indicator more that you are doing something wrong with `i`. If you don't post more of your code we cannot help you.

Comment: @Marty Wallace: if 'i' is a number then result of number+number is a also number. What is the point of the `Number(number)` there then?

Comment: When you do something like: "string" + 4 + "string", the entire process of addition is considered as concatenating a string. So, I do my mathematics within Number().

Comment: var str = "number is " + 5 + 6; **yields number is 56**. var str = "number is " + Number(5 + 6); **yields number is 11**.

Comment: @Matry But just `"number is " + (5 + 6)` will return `"number is 11"` too. The `Number()` function is superfluous, since regular parens get the job done.

Comment: I wasn't saying the () solution is incorrect, I was only justifying my solution. Yes, just parenthesis is superior to the way I knew - this doesn't make using Number() incorrect, just inferior.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "foobar" + (1+i) + "other stuff";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the parseInt method:

```
var str = "foobar" + (parseInt(1+i)) + "other stuff";
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is due to your loop:

```
for (i in imgURLArray){
```

This iterates over all the property *names* of `imgURLArray` as strings. So you will need to use `Number()` to convert `i` to an integer:

```
    str = "<li photonum="+i+">" + "<a>"+ (1+Number(i)) + "</a>" + "</li>";
```